# How to find all Solve::error_names? Or How to Check all except one specific error?

Tags: error-trapping

Basically, all what I want is to use Solve and detect when it can't solve the equation, except for the case when it throws `Solve::ifun` which will consider as OK and will use the solution returned.

So used `Check` on `Solve` command for this purpose, but now I want to tell `Check` to ignore the specific error `Solve::ifun`.

But `Check` does not work this way, instead it wants one to enumerate all the messages that one wants to check! Which makes it hard to use it the other way around, which is: Please catch everything except this error.

MWE: This gives  `Solve::ifun`

```
ClearAll[b, a,c]; 
expr = (b*E^(a*c) - a*E^(b*c))/(E^(a*c) - E^(b*c)); 
sol=Check[Solve[0==expr,c],{}];
If[sol==={},
     Print["I can't solve it"],
     Print["Success, solution is ",sol]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I want is to do something like this, which is not valid

```
sol=Check[Solve[0==expr,c],{}, Except[Solve::ifun]];
```

Instead, one has to enumerate all possible error messages that one wants to catch! But this list can be very long.

So I need to find all possible messages that `Solve` throws and remove `Solve::ifun` from the list? But do not know what all the `Solve::*` messages are. I searched and so far do not find a place they are listed, and I do not know also if `Solve` can throw messages that are not `Solve::` as well.

It will be better if `Check` can be designed to also support `Except`.

**Question**
Is there an easier way to do what I want than what I showed? Is there a place to find all `Solve::*` error messages? Can `Solve` Throw an error which does not start with `Solve::`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you combine `Check[]` and `Quiet[]`:

```
Check[Quiet[Solve[(b*E^(a*c) - a*E^(b*c))/
                  (E^(a*c) - E^(b*c)) == 0, c], Solve::ifun], {}]
```

Comment: I suppose this solution works in general.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the [`InverseFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunctions) option of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve). Compare:

```
Solve[x Exp[x] == 1, x]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> {{x -> ProductLog[1]}}

with:

```
Solve[x Exp[x] == 1, x, InverseFunctions->True]
```

> {{x -> ProductLog[1]}}